Single formula for infinitely many residues of a complex function
I have the following complex function $\frac{(z-1)^2}{(\exp(z) - 1)^3}$. Is it possible to obtain a single formula to express the residues of the function at the third order poles $z=2k\pi i$, where $k$ is an integer number? When I try to apply the formula
$$
\operatorname{Res}[f(z); z_0]=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}(z-z_0)^n f(z)
$$
for $n=3$, I obtain $0$. Instead
$$
\operatorname{Res}[f(z); 0]=5, \ \operatorname{Res}[f(z); 2\pi i]=5-10 i \pi -4 \pi ^2, \ \operatorname{Res}[f(z); 4\pi i]=5-20 i \pi -16 \pi ^2, \ldots
$$
Thanks for any help

Trying with multiple values of $k\in\mathbb Z$, I conjecture that
$$\text{Res}(f,2i\pi k)=5-5i k\pi -(k\pi)^2$$

Try $\text{Res}(f, 2 i \pi k)=5-10 i \pi k-4 \pi^2 k^2$.

If $z = 2 i \pi k + t$,
$$f(z) = \frac{(2 i \pi k - 1 + t)^2}{(e^t-1)^3} =\frac{(2 i \pi k-1)^2 + (4 i \pi k - 2) t + t^2}{t^3 + \frac{3}{2} t^4 + \frac{5}{4} t^5 + \ldots}$$
Now $$\frac{1}{t^3 + \frac{3}{2} t^4 + \frac{5}{4} t^5 + \ldots} = t^{-3} - \frac{3}{2} t^{-2} + t^{-1} + \ldots$$
so the residue, which is the coefficient of $t^{-1}$ in $f(z)$, is
$$\eqalign{1 &- \frac{3}{2} (4 i \pi k - 2) + (2 i \pi k - 1)^2\cr
&= - 4 \pi^2 k^2 - 10 i \pi k + 5}$$

Your result is correct. I don't understand why I obtain zero computing the above limit
